# Firestore Security Rule Allows Reads But Not Creates

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have a top level collection called "readings". Each document in readings has a field called "patientUid".

I have the following security rules:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if false;
    }

    //Takes a uid and returns true if it's the uid of the current user
    function isTheUidOfCurrentUser(uid) {
        return request.auth.uid == uid;
    }

    //A patient or one of their doctors can view their readings
    match /readings/{reading} {
        allow read, write: if isTheUidOfCurrentUser(resource.data.patientUid);
    }

  }
}
```

Currently everything is fine if a user is reads one of the readings, but a user can't create a reading for some reason. What's most strange is the simulator in the console doesn't even show the rule matching when a reading is trying to be created.

What am I doing wrong here. Why does the rule only match on reads, and not on writes?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that resource.data represents the document before the write occurs. Therefore when creating a document, resource.data did not have a patientUid field.

Once I changed

```
resource.data.patientUid
```

to

```
request.resource.data.patientUid
```

it worked since request.resource represents what the document will be after the write.